# Using a trigger to add data to a record

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-object, validation-rule

This sounds like an easy problem but I keep running in to problems.  I am trying to populate a field from one object with data from another object. is this possible with a validation rule or would I need to use apex. For now I am practicing with the book sample object provided here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_qs_customobject.htm

Comment: Validation rules can't be used to populate fields, that's just not part of their functionality. Apex is certainly one option, but there are other options that don't require you to write Apex (e.g. formula fields or workflow field updates). More details about what you're trying to accomplish would help in pointing you to an appropriate solution.

Comment: what is the schema here? and which object is having the DML event verus which object has the field to fetch?  Need more info here

Answer (score 0):

Using process builder is the easiest way to reach your objective.

1. Just create a new process in the process builder under create >
   workflow > process builder
2. Define a start object and the condition. Here choose your source object
3. Then under the action choose the target object and field you want to update, or create a new record.
4. Finally activate the process